# Parse External JSON With JQuery $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, quote

I want to get a quote from iheartquotes and add it to a div when the page loads. I currently have this code but do not know why it wont work

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://iheartquotes.com/api/v1/random?format=json&callback=?', function(data) {
            $(".content").html(json.quote);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And the HTML in the body

```
<div class="content">
This will be replaced with a quote
</div>
```

Comment: Why callback function take "data" argument, but inside callback you use "json" instead "data"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i too agree with @Quentin. This is not possible in client-side as you are trying to access another domain due to Same origin policy.

So you can call a **webservice** / **a static webmethod in an aspx page (using page- methods)** from javascript and do this server side and get back the results client-side itself, where you can do this cross-domain.

The following code may help you to do this in server-side,

You could use **WebClient** for that matter:

```
     using (var client = new WebClient())
     {
      // Define data to be posted
        var values = new NameValueCollection
        {
            { "key1", "value1" },
            { "key2", "value2" },
        };

        // Send the POST request
         byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://foo.com", values);

        // This will contain the cookie being set
        string cookie = client.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

The URL returns JSON, not JSON-P, so you [can't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) read it cross domain with JS in a browser.

You could do this server side instead, or find a third party proxy that could convert it to JSON-P (perhaps YQL).

Comment: http://www.google.se/search?q=php+jquery+ajax+proxy&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:sv-SE:unofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=sv&client=firefox-a&hs=W0v&rls=org.mozilla:sv-SE%3Aunofficial&source=hp&q=php+ajax+proxy&aq=f&aqi=g-L2&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f9b7e5010ae384f8&biw=1920&bih=868